# How to find only rows that are most nearest to a given column value

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a SQL query through which I retrieve those rows from three tables where logtime of all matches and whenever columns st1_vs1_bag4_onoff='0', then corresponding column in different table st1_vs1_bag4_rb will display its value otherwise 0 will be displayed in st1_vs1_bag4_rb.

A beam_current column is also retrieved.Now I want to show only those rows which are very near to beam_current 10,20,30...till 220.only one row corresponding to each value.

I have a SQL query which retrieves rows where beam_current are near to 10,20,30 till 220, but many rows corresponding to each value is retrieve.

My SQL query is:

```
select 
    b.LOGTIME, b.beam_current, b.beam_energy,
    case 
        when a.st1_vs1_bag1_onoff = 0 and a.logtime = c.logtime 
           then c.st1_vs1_bag1_rb 
           else 0 
    end as st1_vs1_bag1_rb,
    case
        when a.st1_vs1_bag2_onoff = '0' and a.logtime = c.logtime 
           then c.st1_vs1_bag2_rb 
           else '0' 
    end as st1_vs1_bag2_rb ,
    case 
        when a.st1_vs1_bag3_onoff = '0' and a.logtime = c.logtime 
           then c.st1_vs1_bag3_rb 
           else '0' 
    end as st1_vs1_bag3_rb,
    case
        when a.st1_vs1_bag4_onoff = '0' and a.logtime = c.logtime 
           then c.st1_vs1_bag4_rb 
           else '0' 
    end as st1_vs1_bag4_rb ,
    case 
        when a.st1_vs1_bag5_onoff = '0' and a.logtime = c.logtime 
           then c.st1_vs1_bag5_rb 
           else '0' 
    end as st1_vs1_bag5_rb ,
    case
        when a.st1_vs1_bag6_onoff = '0' and a.logtime = c.logtime 
           then c.st1_vs1_bag6_rb 
           else '0' 
    end as st1_vs1_bag6_rb ,
    case
        when a.st1_vs1_bag7_onoff = '0' and a.logtime = c.logtime 
           then c.st1_vs1_bag7_rb 
           else '0' 
    end as st1_vs1_bag7_rb ,
    case
        when a.st1_vs1_bag8_onoff = '0' and a.logtime = c.logtime 
           then c.st1_vs1_bag8_rb 
           else '0' 
    end as st1_vs1_bag8_rb 
from 
    INDUS2_BDS.dbo.DCCT b  
inner join
    (main_vacuum_analog c 
inner join 
    main_vacuum_status a on c.logtime = a.logtime) ON a.LOGTIME = b.LOGTIME 
           and (cast(cast(b.beam_current as decimal) % 10.0 as real) <= 0.01 ) OR (cast( cast     (b.beam_current as decimal)% 10.0 as real)>= 9.99))
and (cast(cast(b.beam_current as decimal)as real) >= 9.99) -- to set the lower limit of 9.99
and(cast(cast(b.beam_current as decimal)as real) <= 220.10)
and b.logtime between '2014-10-10 07:17:00' and '2014-10-10 08:46:00'
```

This retrieves around 50 rows corresponding to values near by 10 and so on,in this way it retrieves around 459 rows for all values till 220. Can I just retrieve one row nearest to each value,in this way I will be able to retrieve only 22 rows?

**EDIT 1**

Sample of output through this query is:

[image]

I want a single row whose beam_current value is most near to 10,but I got many rows whose values are near to 10.How to fix this problem??

Comment: Would it be possible to post some sample data for the 3 tables and what the output should be from the sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it looks like you need to pre-process your DCCT table to give you the greatest value in the group (10, 20, 30, 40 ...) for the LogTime.

If my assumption is correct you need to get to the sub query which gives you the Beam_Current with LogTime and then join to your other tables.

Hope the code below helps.

```
declare @DCCT table (LOGTIME datetime, beam_current varchar(10), beam_energy numeric(10,5))

insert into @DCCT (LOGTIME, beam_current, beam_energy)
select '2014-10-10 07:29:31', '9.5',551.0052
union all
select '2014-10-10 07:29:32', '9.61',550.9918
union all
select '2014-10-10 07:29:33', '9.91',551.0052
union all
select '2014-10-10 07:29:34', '9.78',550.9918
union all
select '2014-10-10 07:29:35', '19.5',551.0052
union all
select '2014-10-10 07:29:36', '12.61',550.9918
union all
select '2014-10-10 07:29:37', '15.91',551.0052
union all
select '2014-10-10 07:29:38', '35.5',551.0052
union all
select '2014-10-10 07:29:39', '37.61',550.9918
union all
select '2014-10-10 07:29:40', '210.91',551.0052
union all
select '2014-10-10 07:29:41', '216.91',551.0052


if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp_DCCT') is not null
    drop table #Temp_DCCT

select *
, case
    when cast(beam_current as real) < 10 then 1
    when cast(beam_current as real) >= 10 and cast(beam_current as real) < 20 then 2
    when cast(beam_current as real) >= 20 and cast(beam_current as real) < 30 then 3
    when cast(beam_current as real) >= 30 and cast(beam_current as real) < 40 then 4
    when cast(beam_current as real) >= 40 and cast(beam_current as real) < 50 then 5
    -- add all other groups here .....
    else 6  -- change else to last group
    end as beam_current_grp
into #Temp_DCCT
from @DCCT
where LOGTIME between '2014-10-10 07:17:00' and '2014-10-10 08:46:00'


select *
from
(
    select *
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by beam_current_grp order by beam_current_grp ASC, beam_current DESC) as rownum
    from #Temp_DCCT
) T_DCCT
where rownum = 1
```

The result from the data I used to produce DCCT data will be:

```
LOGTIME                     beam_current    beam_energy     beam_current_grp    rownum
2014-10-10 07:29:33.000     9.91            551.00520       1                   1
2014-10-10 07:29:35.000     19.5            551.00520       2                   1
2014-10-10 07:29:39.000     37.61           550.99180       4                   1
2014-10-10 07:29:41.000     216.91          551.00520       6                   1
```